# Tkinter Retrieving data using column name and plot graph

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, input

I would like to change my code from asking entering the column name manually to asking the user to input it instead based on what which column they want to use? data need to be in dataframe as well

```
def display_graph(data):
    df = pd.read_excel(data)

    # Indicated your x values and y values. 
    x = df[("E-services")]
    y1 = df["Function"]
    y2 = df["Rating(sub)"]
    z = df["Rating(Pol)"]
    y_pos = np.arange(len(x))
```

The result that I wanted is the same as above but just that instead of typed in the column name manually, I can ask the user to input which column that they want to use.

Comment: Are you asking us to write a GUI for you? If you are not familiar with `Tkinter`, [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm) is a good place to start looking at.

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks for the link. I am trying to write a GUI indeed but I can try and do that myself. As you can see from the code, my question is how to get the data by asking the user for input instead of what I did above which is typed in the column name manually.